# PHP Require text between two tags from external document

Tags: php, tags, external

I'm currently using the following code to get the content between two html tags however I would like the string to be from an external .php file.

Code is :-

```
<?php 
    $start = '<status>';
    $end   = '</status>';
    $string = fopen("../../../controls/maintenance.php", "w");
    $output = strstr( substr( $string, strpos( $string, $start) + strlen( $start)), $end, true);
    echo $output;
?>
```

I have tried a few different things but can't get it working.
  Can anyone help? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fopen()` returns a resource and not the files content, you can either use that and `fread()` or you can use `file_get_contents()`

```
$filename = "../../../controls/maintenance.php";
$handle = fopen($filename, "w");
$contents = fread($handle, filesize($filename));
fclose($handle);
```

or the shorter one:

```
$content = file_get_contents("../../../controls/maintenance.php")
```

if you want the PHP parsed, you should use the http:// address of the file

Comment: @WilliamBargent glad i could help! you should click the check next to the up/down arrows to mark this as the answer. That way others can have use for this question in the future, and you contribute to the community =)